# Passing the contents of a file as a parameter in a pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script where I want to pass the contents of a file as a parameter. For example the file could contain something like this

```
asdfadfafd""""""
adfadfaf''  '''adsfa
adsfadfadfafdafadf
```

I want to pass these contents as a single parameter to the pig script. How can I do it?

Comment: what do you want to do with the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can send a single parameter or multiple parameters to a Pig script if you invoke that Pig script from a shell script.

Simply you can initialize a value for a variable inside shell script and then you can pass that value to pig script

lets say your shell script name is demo.sh

```
input_data = "hello";

Pig -P input_data=$input_data /user/cloudera/pigscripts/demo.pig
```

Lets assume the below is your pig code. You can access the parameter in your pig code as below

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,name:chararray);
B = FILTER A by name == '$input_data';
```

Similarly you can pass a file that contains some properties to your pigscript

```
Pig -param_file '/user/cloudera/propertyfiles/file1.txt'  demo.pig
```

By doing so, we can get all variables that is inside file1.txt inside Pigscript using $

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. one is

pig_script.pig:-
R1 = LOAD '$INPUTFILES1' USING PigStorage(',') AS (show_name:chararray, no_of_viewer:int);

pig_param.param:-
INPUTFILES1 = hdfs://192.168.0.107/path-to/input-file

execution command:-
pig -param_file hdfs://192.168.0.107/path-to/pig_param.param hdfs://192.168.0.107/path-to/pig_script.pig